# How I can do spring effect work in android compose?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, animation, android-jetpack-compose

I literally copyed the project in the link bellow and it not work. The app work but without animation.
I'm testing in other projects and don't work. I searched about updates or changes that could be the problem but I don't found nothing about. Somebody could test for me? I want the spring effect.

```
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .animateContentSize(
                animationSpec = spring(
                    dampingRatio = Spring.DampingRatioNoBouncy,
                    stiffness = Spring.StiffnessMedium
                )
            )
```

https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-woof-animation?hl=pt-br&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-compose-unit-3-pathway-3%3Fhl%3Dpt-br%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fbasic-android-kotlin-compose-woof-animation#6

I tried with various versions of android studio and any worked.